# tag merge: fold socks-proxy into socks

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There's two redundant tags: [socks](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/socks) and [socks-proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/socks-proxy).

I propose merging the latter into the former as it's shorter and there's no collision of the name with another term.

Comment: What is this I don't even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done

Comment: Way to sock it to the problem.